# ConvertAPI: Convert HTML to DOCX doesn't work with grid css

Tags: html, docx, convertapi

I want to convert HTML to DOCX have a text with 2 columns inside by using https://www.convertapi.com/
But when I use "display: grid" in HTML file, it doesn't work in DOCX file. I tried with "display: flex", but it doesn't work too. Does it have other CSS to work as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the modern CSS is not supported in DOCX files. What you could do in this case is create a table with two equal columns, or create two inline-block elements that would take up to 50% of space.